# Convert xib to storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib

I have download some sample code. It is about how to load advertisements at launch time. It is cool. But it is a XIB file. I don't know how to convert it to a storyboard.

[Link to githun OPLaunchAd zip](https://github.com/Sean-Wang/OPLaunchAd/archive/master.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually set your Controllers for storyboard. As their is no automatic mechanism for doing so.

Comment: it would have been nice for you to at least give a brief explanation or pointer on how to do this manually..